# Getting signature_invalid calling oauth/request_token for Etsy's API using RestSharp

Tags: c#, oauth, restsharp

I'm trying to use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org) to access Etsy's API. Here's the code I'm using attempting to get an OAuth access token:

```
        var authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiKey"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiSecret"]);

        // same result with or without this next line:
        // authenticator.ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.UrlOrPostParameters;

        this.Client.Authenticator = authenticator;

        var request = new RestRequest("oauth/request_token")
            .AddParameter("scope", "listings_r");

        var response = this.Client.Execute(request);
```

Etsy tells me that the signature is invalid. Interestingly enough, when I enter the timestamp and nonce values generated by the request into this [OAuth signature validation tool](http://support.mashery.com/docs/tips_and_tricks/oAuth), the signatures don't match. Moreover, the URL generated by the tool works with Etsy where the one generated by RestSharp doesn't. Is there something I'm doing wrong or something else I need to configure with RestSharp?

Note: I'm using the version of RestSharp provided by their Nuget package, which at the time of this posting is 102.5.

Comment: might also want to post to http://groups.google.com/group/restsharp

Answer (score 7):

I finally was able to connect to the Etsy API with RestSharp using OAuth.  Here is my code -- I hope it works for you...

```
RestClient mRestClient = new RestClient();

//mRestClient.BaseUrl = API_PRODUCTION_URL;
mRestClient.BaseUrl = API_SANDBOX_URL;
mRestClient.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(API_KEY, 
                                              API_SHAREDSECRET, 
                                              "oob");

RestRequest request = new RestRequest("oauth/request_token", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("scope", 
                     "shops_rw transactions_r transactions_w listings_r listings_w listings_d");

RestResponse response = mRestClient.Execute(request);

if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
   return false;

NameValueCollection queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response.Content);

string oauth_token_secret = queryString["oauth_token_secret"];
string oauth_token = queryString["oauth_token"];

string url = queryString["login_url"];
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);

// BREAKPOINT HERE
string oauth_token_verifier = String.Empty; // get from URL

request = new RestRequest("oauth/access_token");
mRestClient.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForAccessToken(API_KEY,
                           API_SHAREDSECRET,
                           oauth_token,
                           oauth_token_secret,
                           oauth_token_verifier);
response = mRestClient.Execute(request);

if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
  return false;

queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response.Content);

string user_oauth_token = queryString["oauth_token"];
string user_oauth_token_secret = queryString["oauth_token_secret"];
```

The user_oauth_token and user_oauth_token_secret are the user's access token and access token secret -- these are valid for the user until the user revokes access.

I hope this code helps!

Comment: @Daniel Schaffer, did Kris's solution work for you?  I ask because when I try it with my consumer key and secret (but posting to https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/), I get Unauthorised / Signature invalid.  This is driving me mad.

Comment: Basically this code worked for me to _get_ the permanent tokens, but I'm having the 'signature invalid' problem when _using_ those values with `OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(appKey, appSecret, accessKey, accessSecret);`